# Am I oversimplifying the concept of " if a string is one edit away"?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, edit

I've been doing a good amount of studying and practicing algorithms, and I ran into one that asked the question (summarizing here) "Given two strings, return True if the strings are one edit away (either by removing, inserting, or replacing a character). Return False if not."

I went about this problem by comparing two strings and counting the amount of letters that are in string1, but not in string2. If there is more than one letter missing, then it will return False.

Here is my Python code:

```
def oneAway(string1, string2):
    string1 = string1.lower()
    string2 = string2.lower()
# counts the number of edits required
    counter = 0
    for i in string1:
        if i not in string2:
            counter += 1
    if counter > 1:
       return False
    else:
        return True
```

I'd like to hear other people's approaches to this problem, and please point out if I have oversimplified this concept.

Comment: What happens if you call `oneAway('abcde', 'edcba')`? Those are certainly not identical and quite a few edits separated?

Comment: Consider a situation where two strings have the same characters but in different permutations. Your algorithm would return True in a situation where the strings are more than 1 edit away.

Comment: To both of you: that is very true. I failed to catch that when I initially thought about it.

Comment: As a tip, the fact that the question is "Is the string one edit away?" implies that the approach should *not* be "first find the edit distance, then compare that number to 1" (If it was, the question would just be "what is the edit distance?"). You can compare the strings character by character, and once you find a difference, you can make your one edit (tip: check the string lengths), and then make sure that the rest of the strings are the same, aka requires 0 additional edits.

Comment: @thatotherguy I like that method. Thank you for the reply

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63115236/one-edit-distance-away/63116633#63116633

Comment: Solve by calculating levenstein distance and then check if that is <=1.

Answer (score 0):

Why call `.lower()` on both strings? Based on the question, `oneAway('abc', 'ABC')` should be False.

Building off of the other comments, how about this:

```
def oneAway(s1, s2):
    i, j = 0, 0
    mistake_occurred = False
    
   
    while i < len(s1) and j < len(s2):
        if s1[i] != s2[j]:
            if mistake_occurred:
                return False
            mistake_occurred = True 
        i += 1
        j += 1
             
    if mistake_occurred and (i != len(s1) or j != len(s2)):
        return False
    if i < len(s1) - 1 or j < len(s2) - 1:
        return False
    
    return True
```

Comment: oneAway('A','BA')  returns False

Answer (score 0):

You have to check each editing action specifically:

```
def isOneEdit(A,B):
    # replacing one char
    if len(A) == len(B) and sum(a!=b for a,b in zip(A,B)) == 1:
        return True
    # inserting one char in A to get B
    if len(A) == len(B)-1 and any(A==B[:i]+B[i+1:] for i in range(len(B))):
        return True
    # removing one char (like inserting one in B to get A)
    if len(A) == len(B)+1: 
        return isOneEdit(B,A)
    return False

print(isOneEdit("abc","abd"))   # True - replace c with d

print(isOneEdit("abd","abcd"))  # True - insert c 

print(isOneEdit("abcd","abd"))  # True - delete c

print(isOneEdit("abcde","abd")) # False
```

Alternatively, you can compare the size of the common prefix and suffix of the two strings to the length of the longest one:

```
def isOneEdit(A,B):
    if abs(len(A)-len(B))>1: return False
    commonPrefix = next((i for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(A,B)) if a!=b),len(A))
    commonSuffix = next((i for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(reversed(A),reversed(B))) if a!=b),len(B))
    editSize     = max(len(A),len(B)) - (commonPrefix+commonSuffix) 
    return editSize <= 1
```